# SageMaker - What IAM Permission to specify for ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

## Question

Is this the ECR IAM permission required for SageMaker to use the XGBoost of the [Amazon SageMaker built-in algorithms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algos.html) in the **us-west-1** region?

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
  "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
  "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
  "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
  "ecr:BatchGetImage"
],
"Resource": [
  "arn:aws:ecr:us-west-1:632365934929:repository/632365934929.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:1"
]
```

## Background

The AWS document [Amazon SageMaker Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html#sagemaker-roles-createnotebookinstance-perms) tells to specify **TrainingImage** value of the **CreateTrainingJob** API.

```
Scope ecr permissions as follows:
- Scope to the AlgorithmSpecification.TrainingImage value that you specify in a CreateTrainingJob request.
- Scope to the PrimaryContainer.Image value that you specify in a CreateModel request:


"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
  "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
  "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
  "ecr:BatchGetImage"
],
"Resource": [
  "arn:aws:ecr:::repository/my-repo1",
  "arn:aws:ecr:::repository/my-repo2",
  "arn:aws:ecr:::repository/my-repo3"
]
```

The AWS SageMaker API document [TrainingImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_AlgorithmSpecification.html#sagemaker-Type-AlgorithmSpecification-TrainingImage) tells to specify the algorithm **docker image registry path** as the value.

> **TrainingImage**
>   The **registry path of the Docker image** that contains the training
>   algorithm. For information about docker registry paths for built-in
>   algorithms, see Algorithms Provided by Amazon SageMaker: Common
>   Parameters. Amazon SageMaker supports both **registry/repository[:tag]**
>   and registry/repository[@digest] image path formats.

The AWS document [Common parameters for built-in algorithms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-algo-docker-registry-paths.html) indicates the XGBoost registry path is `632365934929.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:1`.

> |Algorithm name|Training image and inference image registry path|
>   |XGBoost       | **ecr_path**/xgboost:**tag**|
>   
>   **ecr_path** (Algorithms: BlazingText, ..., Seq2Seq, and XGBoost (0.72)
>   | us-west-1 | 632365934929.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com |
>
> For the Training Image and Inference Image Registry Path column, **use the :1 version tag** to ensure that you are using a stable version of the algorithm. You can reliably host a model trained using an image with the :1 tag on an inference image that has the :1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

As per the note on page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-algo-docker-registry-paths.html

```
For XGBoost, do not use :latest or :1. Use the specific version you require, such as :0.90-1-cpu-py3, :0.90-2-cpu-py3, :1.0-1-cpu-py3, or :1.2-1.
```